# jQuery - Very simple issue i cant sort out (class's and an alert)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this may be my most embarrassing question to date.

Why does this not work? Ive been staring at this for around half an hour now and im starting to get desperate

http://jsfiddle.net/FU6Jb/

My HTML

```
<a class="closedialog" href="#">Close</a>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.closedialog").click(function() {
        alert("Test")
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to inlude jQuery in your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FU6Jb/1/

Comment: Your code is working...Just change the framework to jquery and run your code

Comment: That easy to fix? Damn... The problem is still there in the work i am actually working on, but its a good 1000 lines of code. I thought i had condensed it down to the code above as the problem. Thanks for the input btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the jQuery library, at the left panel.

This fiddle does work: http://jsfiddle.net/FU6Jb/1/

More explanation on JSFiddle. The dropdown box above the Framework indicates where the code should be inserted. Using your current setup, your JavaScript code will be wrapped in a onload event. I recommend to use the `nowrap (head)` option.

[image]

Comment: +1 You answer very fast! I was just writing this as an comment and recognized that you've updated the fiddle before me already.